# Extend, modify, or override Joomla's bootstrap.php?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.1

So I've been playing with Joomla 3 with Bootstrap.  At first I didn't fully understand what they meant by Bootstrap being baked into the CMS - seems like you could call it but would have to either use Javascript or template overrides to match the expected output. Not much more convenient than calling the Bootstrap framework manually.

Then I found a few links about `libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php` - and there was much rejoicing:

- http://doc.joomladev.eu/api3/Joomla-Libraries/HTML/JHtmlBootstrap.html;
- https://groups.google.com/group/joomla-dev-cms/browse_thread/thread/59ede023a635cc78/18f67450a08e66ff?lnk=raot;
- http://itprism.com/blog/106-bootstrap-tabs-accordion-slides.

This seems to be a work in progress, and the limited links I found indicate that there are some kinks to be worked out. But useful for going forward...especially if I can create or edit my own as needed.

1. Is there a way of using this file in a template override, like modules.php?
2. Is there any better documentation than what I listed above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a JHtml helper, you would use it like any other JHtml call you see in the CMS.  As you probably know, `JHtml::_('behavior.framework');` enables MooTools in the CMS.  Well, there's a similar function `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');` that will load the Bootstrap JavaScript as well as its jQuery dependency.  So, if you want to enable Bootstrap's alert plugin, just call `JHtml::_('bootstrap.alert', 'optionalClassNameForAlertElements');` and you're all set.

Bootstrap has less than a year in the CMS while MooTools has been around for a while, so obviously the support can still be improved upon.  But, we've tried to make it easy to quickly enable the various Bootstrap JavaScript plugins so you can focus on front-end work.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't even realize you could use your own selectors, sweet!  Like I said, I discovered this after a lot of searching - very cool.  What if you needed to modify this output?  Is there a way of extending or modifying the bootstrap.php output - like in a template override?

Comment: In 3.1, some of the tab items are converted to use the JLayout feature.  Those are overridable.  For the methods that are just adding the required JavaScript snippet to the `<head>`, you shouldn't need to override those.  That does leave a few methods that don't have overridable markup for now, but there is a goal to move markup to JLayout snippets that can be overridden, so eventually you should be able to customize everything with ease.

Comment: Thanks - this all makes a lot more sense.

Comment: You can use own JHtml classes instead default ones using `JHtml::addIncludePath `or `JHtml::unregister`+ `JHtml::register`, but depending on the setup this should happen rather early (best during `onAfterRoute`).